# SCOM agent install fails with error 0x80070002

Tags: scom

When trying to install Windows agents in SCOM 2012 R2, the task fails with error 0x80070002. Looking in the agent install log at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\Operations Manager\Server\AgentManagement\AgentLogs` I see "OmAgentFunctions::InstallOmAgentMsi : MsiInstallProductW() failed. HResult: 80070643".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to push the agent from the SCOM server, try running the agent installer manually from the target server. The installer GUI may give you a better idea of why the install failed.

In my case the problem was that the System Center Advisor Agent was installed, which can not co-exist with the SCOM agent.